# Route-Level <onException> doesn't catch exception when transacitonal commit occurs?

Tags: exception, apache-camel, spring-transactions

Using Camel 2.13.2. Bear with me while I lay my problem out:

I have a sub-process where I need to keep track of inflight orders. The main process uses a long transaction that persists order information at the end of some lengthy validation. If two orders with the same key are submitted subseconds apart, there is a chance that the pending order validation will not flag the last order in. Because of this, I have a route that uses a new transaction with PROPIGATION_REQIRES_NEW to persist the inflight info to supplement the pending order validation until relevant order info is committed down the line:

```
<route id="insertInflightRoute">
        <from uri="direct-vm:insertInflightEndpoint"/>          
        <transacted ref="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW" />
```

`<exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>`

```
            <bean ref="inflightService" method="setInflightException"/>
        </onException>

        <!-- DB insert via Mybatis autowired in bean. Working fine-->
        <bean ref="inflightService" method="insert"/>
    </route>
```

When the second order tries to insert into this inflight table, a PK violation exception is thrown once the transaction tries to commit. This is also working fine.

**My issue is that the route-level `<onException>` is skipped when this route's transaction fails to commit due to PK violation. I get back the not- so-nice PK violation exception instead of the readable exception the customer would see**

1. Should the route-level `<onException>` be able to handle exceptions caused during transactional commits? I think so...

**I'd like to note that a route-level** `<onCompletion onFailureOnly="true">` **DOES make the reinterpretation like I want**, but it is basically a wireTap which does me no good since I need the reinterpreted exception passed to our complex global error handler on the original thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround solution to my problem though is not as ideal as I would like.

I went back to the calling route and encased the `<to uri...>` in a `<doTry>` and reinterpret my exception there. Transaction committal failures are now handled the way I want them to be by throwing the exception from setInflightException bean call:

```
        <doTry>
            <!-- insert into inflight mdn table immediately -->
            <to uri="direct-vm:insertInflightEndpoint"/>
        <doCatch>
            <exception>java.sql.SQLException</exception>
            <bean ref="inflightService" method="setInflightException"/>
        </doCatch>
        </doTry>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the route level onException to alter the original exchange/message you need to set it to handle it, eg handled=true, and then in the bean you can set a new exception on the exchange, or throw an exception.

Comment: Hey Claus, thanks for the response. I get what you are saying but my issue is that route-level onException isn't used when a transaction fails to commit at the end of the route. Instead, it is going to the global exception handlers. I suppose what I'm asking is if this is expected behavior since a route-level onCompletion does encompass the transaction commit attempt.